# C++ - Array elements yield different values in for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, element, addition

I have a global int array declared in a header file (Uni.h) like so :

```
int durationArray[];
```

My program will run and assign elements to the array (2 in this case). But what stumps me is that at the array elements yield different values if i use a for loop to display them and when I manually use cout to display them. Here is my code :

```
cout << "durationArray at element 0 is :" << durationArray[0] << endl;
cout << "durationArray at element 1 is :" << durationArray[1] << endl;

int counting=2;             
for (int i=0; i<counting; i++)
{
    cout << "durationArray at element " << i << ": " << durationArray[i] << endl;
}
```

Here is the output :

```
durationArray at element 0 is :3
durationArray at element 1 is :4


durationArray at element 0: 0
durationArray at element 1: 4
```

My ultimate aim is to get the sum of the array elements. But how do I accomplish this if the element values are wrong when i iterate through the array using a for loop? I plan to use this code for the addition :

```
for (int i=0; i<counting; i++)
    {
        sumofDuration+=durationArray[i];
    }
```

Comment: Use `std::accumulate` to sum elements, not a loop. The loop isn't wrong, but it's not idiomatic and it's not as immediately clear that a summation is being done.

Comment: Reverse the blocks (do the manual accessing after the loops).  Are the results the same? Are you sure you're not doing something to overwrite the array?

Comment: How is the array defined and initialized?

Comment: Where is definition of that array?

Comment: This shouldn't compile since you are not declaring the array correctly.

Comment: How would I use std::accumulate to sum up the elements without a loop?

Comment: Is this all your code? Or does something else happen with durationArray?

Comment: `int a[];` outside of a function is illegal in C++ (perhaps your compiler has a extension, but who knows what it does).  `extern int a[];` is legal though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) , it is that simple :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  auto array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  std::cout << std::accumulate(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Or [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with a lambda (more flexible if your accumulator gets complicated) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  auto array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  int sum { 0 };
  std::for_each(begin(array),end(array),[&](int n){
                        sum += n;  
    });
  std::cout << sum;
  return 0;
}
```